# How to run jstat in windows?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jstat

I am trying to run `jstat` for monitoring `GC`. I get the `vmid` using `jps` command:

```
> jps
18928 GCTest
```

but when i try to run `jstat` like this:

```
>jstat -gc <vmid> 18928
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I get the message `The system cannot find the file specified.` . The syntax seems fine. Am i making any errors?

Comment: is jstat in your class path?

Comment: yes it is , i am able to execute jstat command, but when i try to execute with the argument it is showing me the message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call it like this, this should work:

```
jstat -gc 18928
```

Comment: but why i couldn't use <vmid> option?

Comment: AFAIK <vmid> is either the name of the JVM or the id (which you got using the jps command). So you don't have to put it in the command line.

Comment: <vmid> is the syntax for the parameter placeholder, so you are using it